# JQueryUI Datepicker Event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

i have 2 input form using jqueryui datepicker:
1. begin date
2. end date

what i want is, when i select date from "begin date" then datepicker on "end date" only display date after "begin date". so it will not display date longer/older then "begin date". how to make it happen?

thanks

```
<input id="start" type="text">
<input id="end" type="text">
<script>
var myDate = '';
$(function(){
$('#start').datepicker({
onSelect: function(date){
myDate = $(this).val();
}
});
$('#end').datepicker({
minDate: myDate
});
});</script>
```

thats my script, but not working.

Comment: show us the code u tried

Comment: <input type="text" id="start_date">
<input type="text" id="end_date">
var mydate;
$(function(){
$('#start_date').datepicker({
onSelect: mydate = $(this).val();
});
$('#end_date').datepicker(
{
minDate: mydate;
}
);
});

sorry thats my code, but not working.

Answer (score 2):

Check the date range example in the jquery ui website. Check the source under this example.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting and fairly complicated problem. You need a few things to start with.

1. Both datepickers min and max must be set on load based on the opposing date field. This default min and maxing can be accomplished as follows:

   A. Get predata from date-fields with jQuery

   ```
   var initDateBegin = $('#beginField').val(),
       initDateEnd   = $('#endField').val();
       initDateBegin = new Date(initDateBegin);
       initDateEnd   = new Date(initDateEnd);
   ```

   B. Then we can pass these into the Datepicker constructor using the datepicker `minDate` and `maxDate` options: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate. But we also need an offset so users do not set begin and end to the same date. I use the date.js library when its time for heavy date manipulations: http://www.datejs.com/

   ```
    $('#beginField').datePicker({ maxDate : initDateEnd.addDays(-1) });
    $('#endField').datePicker({ minDate : initDateBegin.addDays(1) });
   ```
2. Next we need the datepickers to update each other's limits. So..

   A. We need to set up a listener on both datefields so that after the user selects a new date on either Begin or End dates, the opposing fields limits get updated. This really should be done in the datepicker constructor( with the `onClose` method http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onClose), so now we have something like this:

   ```
    $('#beginField').datePicker({ 
           maxDate : initDateEnd.addDays(-1),
           onClose : setMin
    });
    $('#endField').datePicker({ 
           minDate : initDateBegin.addDays(1),
           onClose : setMax
    });
   ```

   B. So now its time to setup functions that will actually change the min and max of each picker

   ```
   function setMin(newMinDate){
         //convert to date object
         newMinDate = new Date(newMinDate); 
         //set new min date on end datepicker
         $('#endField').datepicker('option', 'minDate', newMinDate.addDays(-1));                          
   }

   function setMax(newMaxDate){
         //convert to date object
         newMaxDate = new Date(newMaxDate); 
         //set new max date on begin datepicker
         $('#beginField').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', newMaxDate.addDays(1));                          
   }
   ```
3. This should at least point you in the right direction but there is more you may need to consider.

   A. Is there an absolute max an min to account for? Like for example, the range pickable by beginning and end must not be in the future, so an upper limit of Today, and must not be before 1990, or a lower limit of 1990. If this is the case, you will have to add additional catches in the system to prevent the user from picking dates that invalidate the absolute limits.

   B. If you want mobile support? If so you will have to use html5 date fields for mobile, and NOT use html5 date fields on desktops (because desktop browsers may have built in datepickers)

   C. The jquery-ui datepicker does not stop people from using their keyboards to type dates and bypass the datepicker. So you will need to either

   - Prevent keyboard input all together, forcing the user to use the datepicker (keydown and preventDefault() should do it.)
   - Add additional scripting to account for parsing hand typed dates, policing limits from there and translating it to have effect in the setMin and setMax functions. This can basically be reused to work with a mobile (non jquery-ui) version, as long as you don't user the datepicker to update opposing fields after parseing. Lastly parseing hand typed dates is another good reason to use Date.js, which is truely an awesome script.

Good luck!